# how to give a space by joining 2 columns having repeated data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


+----+--------+------+--------+
| id | userid | loan | name   |
+----+--------+------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |  100 | x |
|  2 |      1 |  200 | X|
|  3 |      2 | 2000 | y|
|  4 |      3 | 1000 | z|
|  5 |      1 |  500 | a|
|  6 |      2 |  700 | b|
```

As you can see userid is repeating.For example userid 1 is having loan 100,200 and 500

My requirement is to get userid,loan and name and if the userid is repating then loan will be the sum of the repeating userid and name should be space
for example,In the above table userid 1 is repeating so sum is (100+200+500=800)
similarly for userid 2 the sum is 2700
The output i want should be like the below

```
+--------+-----------+----+
| userid | SUM(loan) |name|
+--------+-----------+----+
|      1 |       800 |    |
|      2 |      2700 |    |
|      3 |      1000 |z   |
+--------+-----------+
```

I can do with userid and loan but I dont know how to put a space in name field if the userid is repeating

I tried like this

```
SELECT userid,SUM(loan) FROM
testforsum
GROUP BY userid
```

and the ouput I am getting is like this

```
+--------+-----------+
| userid | SUM(loan) |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |       800 |
|      2 |      2700 |
|      3 |      1000 |
+--------+-----------+
```

I tried to create a sqlfiddle for it but I dont know why insertion is not happening.You can see the table [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80b93)

Comment: So, you're wanting to display a space in the name field if they have more than one loan, and the actual name if they only have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select q.userid, q.s, 
       case when q.n > 1 then ' ' else q.name end
from
(SELECT userid, SUM(loan) s, count(loan) n, max(name) name
FROM testforsum GROUP BY userid) q;
```

Some explanation:

`(...) q` is a subquery which calculates for each userId sum of loans (NULLS are ignored), number of loans (NULLS are ignored).

`max(name)` it's a "fake" aggregate function, I used it to get any name for each userId (they are all the same for each userId so I can do that) because in ANSI SQL this query is wrong:

```
SELECT userid, IF(COUNT(*) > 1, ' ', name) AS name, SUM(loan) 
FROM testforsum GROUP BY userid;
```

as all the expressions in the SELECT list should be either aggregate functions (for several rows return a single value) or expressions from the GROUP BY clause. As I know MySQL lets you break these rules, but I prefer to follow ANSI whenever it's possible.

So the subquery **q** results in a table with unique userIds with their names + sum and number of their loans.

Finally, the parent query filters the result of the **q** subquery using CASE.

Comment: There's no need for the subquery. Just do the `CASE` directly on the `COUNT`.

Comment: @Patrick Q Thanks for info. I used a subquery to make it clearer

Comment: @rocking To be honest, my answer came first.

Comment: @Multisync yes sorry your answer came first.The other answer is having less code and the output is exactly as per requirement.YOur answer is also helpful

Comment: @Multisync can you explain the answer?

Comment: @Multisync thanks,I could not understand this line *IF(COUNT(*) > 1, ' ', name) AS name* of the other answer.Can you please explain this?

Comment: @rocking It's just a MySQL function which results in some expression: IF([condition], [expr1], [expr2]) = IF [condition] is true THEN [expr1] ELSE [expr2]. An example: if(1 > 2, 'hmm', 'rabbish') = 'rabbish'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT userid, IF(COUNT(*) > 1, ' ', name) AS name, SUM(loan) 
FROM testforsum GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.I could not understand this part *IF(COUNT(*) > 1, ' ', name) AS name*.It would be nice if you please explain this in your answer

Comment: @rocking as said by Multisync, it's a MySQL function, see the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if